# Inserting command into app

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-store-apps, command-prompt

could someone tell me  to open all applications on windows 7 using command prompt by inserting the command into an app so when the app is opened the command is launched/executed then all the apps are opened. I want to crash my computer a fun way. please don't judge.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because stackoverflow is for **real** programming problems and real developers. Crashing a computer is not one of those.

Comment: Besides, based on what misinformed opinion do you assume to *"crash"* a machine by exercising the most mundane operation: Launching processes?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's not really a good way to do that, since there's no easy way to get paths to the executables for every program installed on the computer.

Something like

```
forfiles /p "%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu" /m *.lnk /s /C "cmd /C start \"\" @path"
```

would launch everything in the 'All Programs' list in the start menu, but that includes stuff like uninstallers, web links, help files, as well as all the programs themselves.

EDIT: To explain that command a bit, `forfiles` will go through all the files in the specified folder (see http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html).

The folder we are specifying is the location where all the shortcuts in the start menu are located.

The `/m` mask makes the command only look at shortcuts (`*.lnk` files).

The `/s` makes it look through subdirectories, rather than just the base directory.

And the `/C` is the command we are running on each file. In this case, that command is to launch a cmd prompt that starts the file.